# Why does this VB.NET respond differently on remote server compared to local server?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have a VB.NET application that requests an xml file and converts the data into readable HTML content.

On the remote server it seems the values for some of the variables does **not** extract the value from the xml, and then proceed to display HTML content without these values.

Local server (local machine) the values for the variables **is** extracted from the xml, and it is then displayed correctly.

I have IIS 7 on both machines, and remote server is using 4.5 .NET Framework while local is using 4.0 .

In order to troubleshoot I want to upgrade my .NET Framework to 4.5 to see why this .

Am I looking in the wrong place to solve this issue or should I continue to try and update my local machine's .NET framework?

Comment: It's rare (but not unheard of) for a framework difference to cause different functionality. Usually something either works or throws an exception when a feature isn't supported / a library is missing. I'd start by making sure you're catching and logging/displaying all exceptions (not swallowing any silently), then change your code to add some logging information (Alternatively, you could attach a remote debugger and step through the code but that tends to require a bit more set up)

Comment: Problem is that the remote server has 2GB ram, and barely loads the webpage in IE. I would like to do debugging locally if possible.

Comment: When I say "remote debugging", I don't mean installing Visual Studio on the server, I mean connecting your local VS to the server and interacting with a process running there. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bt727f1t(v=vs.100).aspx for an introduction

Comment: Oh and I took over the project, from someone that seems to know very little of programming, SQL injection vulnerability was just the first thing I noticed. I am not familiar with VB.NET and this is not the only thing driving me nuts.

Comment: The problem is, you haven't provided enough information in the question for us to begin to debug the problem, so we need more details. You   could provide us with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but I suspect that will be difficult with a complex server process. Failing that, you either have to get some log information to see what's going on, or attach a debugger and step through the code.